# Selenium TestNG based Maven Test does not show the Test Results using JavaSE-17

Tags: selenium, maven, testng, pom.xml, java-17

Selenium TestNG based Maven Test does not show the Test Results

I have a Selenium (selenium-server-4.3.0) project with the following Environment:

- Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
- Version: 2022-06 (4.24.0)
- JavaSE-17
- Installed JRE: jdk-17.0.3.1

Code:

```html
package com.in.i2i;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TC_Login {

    @Test
    public void loginTest()
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.id("txtUsername")).sendKeys("Admin");
        driver.findElement(By.id("txtPassword")).sendKeys("admin123");
        driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin")).click();
        Assert.assertEquals(driver.getTitle(), "OrangeHRM");
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

which executes perfectly as ***TestNG Test***:

```html
PASSED: loginTest

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Passes: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Using the pom.xml:

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.in.i2i</groupId>
  <artifactId>testSeleniumProject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  
  <properties>
         <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
         <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties> 

  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
    <dependency>
          <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
          <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
          <version>7.3.0</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

when trying to execute the Test as a *`Maven Test`* it shows only *BUILD SUCCESS* and the test results aren't shown.

```html
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------< com.in.i2i:testSeleniumProject >-------------------
[INFO] Building testSeleniumProject 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ testSeleniumProject ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ testSeleniumProject ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ testSeleniumProject ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ testSeleniumProject ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ testSeleniumProject ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.682 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-07-12T03:38:58+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Can someone help me if I am missing something and point me to the right direction?

Comment: Upgrade all plugins you are using... literally all of them ...even the one suggested in the answer...is giving an old version... use most recent version of plugin...  https://maven.apache.org/plugins/ also fix your encoding problem: https://maven.apache.org/general.html#encoding-warning furthermore if you really using JDK17 you should use `<maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>` instead of source/target configuration.

Comment: @khmarbaise Plugins- all are default, I'm not sure how I should force upgrade them. Can you point me to the right direction please? `<maven.compiler.release>` I'll change it and update you the result.

Comment: `Plugins- all are default, I'm not sure how I should force upgrade them.` using pluginManagement and define the versions (for example: https://github.com/khmarbaise/smpp/blob/master/pom.xml#L94)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add Maven surfire plugin under project section. Under suiteXml you need to mention your testng.xml file name.

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testNgSuite.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>iso-8859-1</encoding>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Using an old version of surefire, also using the wrong encoding because the output of the original implies that UTF-8 is used.. furthermore not defined most recent version of maven-compiler-plugin ...